# When I changed my phone time, doesn't return actual time?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I want to keep actual post date-time as UTC but after disable to "Set auto" from iPhone Settings and changing, posting time goes wrong.

How Can I prevent this?

```
    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    let utcTimeZoneStr = formatter.string(from: date)
```

> This solved my problem using Swift 3:

https://github.com/lyft/Kronos

Comment: `Date()` gives whatever time is showing on the iOS device.

Comment: @rmaddy Okay, But Is there any way to check this? or get as true.

Comment: @rmaddy It's answered with Objective-C. I should get it as Swift.

Comment: It's not answered with any language. The answer points you in the general direction of accessing an ntp server.

Comment: @rmaddy Maybe that can be https://github.com/instacart/TrueTime.swift I will try it. Thanks.